# Slice 6 random items from array

Tags: slice

I have an array with 400 items, each item is a JSON object.

I need to return 6 random items from the arr(6 JSON objects) using the slice method.

my code :

```
data.slice("here I need to return 6 random items ").map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div class="caption">
                <img
                  src={item.avatar + `/${index}`}
                  key={index}
                  alt="avatar"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                />
                <center>
                  {item.firstname + " " + item.lastname}
                  <h5 class="job"> {item.job}</h5>
                </center>{" "}
              </div>
            </>
```

how can I do this? I used Math. random but it's don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shuffle the array with [something like that](https://javascript.info/task/shuffle) :

```
function shuffle(array) {
  array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

and then a `.slice(0,6)` will give you 6 randomized items